# how to completely remove vs-code setting?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

After I uninstalled `vs-code` the popup message appeared:

```
Your extensions and settings will not be removed.
```

Now I want to remove all of the `vs-code` settings and install it as a new user. How can I do this?

Comment: What system are you using?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

If you want to completely delete settings, go to `%AppData%\Code` and delete the whole folder. Then uninstall and install it again.

If you want to delete all extensions too, delete the `extensions` folder on `%UserProfile%\.vscode`.

Comment: copy pastable paths: %AppData%\Code %userprofile%\.vscode

Comment: what about macos

Comment: Guide for MacOs: https://medium.com/@jimkang/complete-uninstall-remove-vscode-mac-5e48bef3bdec

Comment: on linux on your home folder type ll and find the hidden folder .vscode and run command

word of caution, please be careful with this rm -rf command as this is dangerous when not use right.
```
   sudo  rm -rf .vscode

```

Comment: This is really bad advice you are going to mess up vscode.

Comment: If your vscode is disconnected from wsl, also remove the bin folder in `/home/your-user/.vscode-server/bin` with `rm -r`

Comment: On linux User settings is stored on `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json` . You will need to delete this folder too `~/config/Code/` if you want to get rid of all VS Code configuration, extensions and other related staff.

Please, make a backup before deleting it if you are unsure about what you are doing.

Answer (score -3):

Although you can use `rm` to do this its safer to use the `code` command line.
Example: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line