# VisualStudioCode editor.showUnused true not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the setting `show unused` on true (both User and Workspace).

[image]

But unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. As you can see the "unused" import look the same as the other imports.

[image]

I am using **Visual Studio Code 1.42.0** (but I had the same issue on older versions)

Comment: Maybe some extension decoration conflict? Does it repro with all extension disabled? `code --disable-extensions`

Comment: @Alex I still have the issue with all extensions disabled (except for Node Debug that won't let me disable it for some reason)

Comment: Then you might want to report it to vscode repo https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues (likely with more details).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by uninstalling VS code *completely* (You have to manually delete some files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52462074/3904557) and reinstalling it.

### EDIT FROM Leon Gaban: From link in answer that worked

Had to completely uninstall VScode and run some extra rm -rf commands
https://jimkang.medium.com/complete-uninstall-remove-vscode-mac-5e48bef3bdec

Step 1

```
rm -rf $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code
// add sudo if you needed to
// if you're using insider*
sudo rm -rf $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code\ -\ Insiders/
```

Step 2

```
rm -rf $HOME/.vscode
// add sudo if you needed to
// if you're using insider*
sudo rm -rf $HOME/.vscode-insiders/
```

Comment: This is the actual fix to this issue. Many other answers make you think it's related to a setting when that setting is default.