# Unable to resolve resource walkThrough://vscode_getting_started_page

Tags: visual-studio-code

This error will be reported every time I open it, and the software is not resolved after reinstalling.

Comment: What's "it"? I mean "ill be reported every time I open **it**, and t"

Answer (score 3):

I was on that issue too. These are the steps I followed to get it resolved:

1. Go to **Files**.
2. Click on **Preferences**.
3. Click on **Settings**.
4. Look for "**workbench.editorAssociations**" and delete the item with a `*` (wildcard) value.

Answer (score 0):

okay i encountered the same problem and had to look for solutions. For my case deleting the config file from the terminal solved it

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.config/Code
sudo rm -rf ~/.vscode
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with welcome page, getting started and interactive playground. here is a link that shows a few extra steps after uninstalling.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52462074/16295473